# Java ucanaccess library through command prompt

Tags: java, jar, ms-access-2007, command-prompt, relative-path

I want to know how to assign the relative path of ucanaccess libraries in command prompt to run java to access MS-ACCESS 2007 as :-

```
     C:\Project>java -cp [RELATIVE PATH (including "*.jar" in lib folder if possible)] [primary name of java class]
```

Comment: Can you explain, what exactly your problem is? Is the meaning of "relative path" unclear to you?

Comment: I downloaded the latest binaries: UCanAccess-3.0.3.1-bin.zip. The contained batch file cosole.bat is a perfect example of setting the classpath to start a Java program with all the needed libraries.